# Read binary file using fread()

Tags: c, file, fread

I'm trying to read a binary file with fread() function.
I want to read 2 byte every time (UTF-16 file).
The relative code:

```
char words[2];
while(fread(&words, sizeof(words), 1, sFile))
//do somthing...
```

The information from the file is stored only in the first place of the array, and the second stay as zero. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: "the second stay as zero" --> because the data in the file is zero - every other byte.

Comment: Can you explain please? thank you

Comment: How do you write to the file? How do you initialize the data you write? What does `fread` returns? What does `fwrite` (which I assume you use to write) return? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing both writing and reading.

Comment: Try this: `char words[2] = {0xaa};` and see if you observe change from `0xaa` to some other value.

Comment: On another (but unrelated note) you should very seldom use the address-of operator `&` on an array (like you do with `&words`).  When writing an array using `fwrite` (and reading using `fread`) you should pass a pointer to *the first element* which you do with `&words[0]` (or plain `words` as that will decay to the same). The type of `&words[0]` (and therefore plain `words`) is `char *`. The type of `&words` is `char (*)[2]`. Semantically very different.

Comment: If the file contains UTF-16 encoded text written in the basic Latin alphabet (or using characters from the ASCII code set), then the UTF-16 values will be U+0020..U+007E, and those are encoded in UTF-16 as one byte containing `0x20`..`0x7E` and the other containing `0x00`.  Assuming you're using Intel hardware, you have little-endian encoding, so the first byte might be 0x41 (`A` in ISO 8859-1) and the second would be 0x00.

Comment: @vasek Better to try `char words[2] = {0xaa, 0x55};` and set both to non-zero.

Comment: @puhs "and the second stay as zero." --> This could be a problem of how you determined the second was zero.  Best to post a [mcve] that include the print out of `words[0]` and `words[1]` and the data in the binary file that was read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank to you all, I found the mistake -
In UTF-16, every char is 2 byte, and the "regular" chars are with zero in the 2nd byte.
Again, thank you.

Comment: Though, giving attribution is very much recommended, when writing answer based on what other people wrote.